# How to stop XEmacs from teaching me that my keyboard settings are "bad"?

Tags: keyboard-layout, xemacs

I've changed (using the keyboard layout options in Linux Mint 13) the keyboard layout as follows:

- The Caps Lock key is reconfigured as Compose key.
- Pressing both Shift keys at once toggles Caps Lock.

Since both options are offered by the menus (no `xmodmap` or similar involved), I figure they should work fine, and indeed, I've never noticed any problems (including inside XEmacs), with one exception:

Whenever I start XEmacs (version 21.4.22), I get an extra window (in the Emacs sense of "window") with the following text:

```
(1) (key-mapping/warning) 
    The meanings of the modifier bits Mod1 through Mod5 are determined
    by the keysyms used to control those bits.  Mod1 does NOT always
    mean Meta, although some non-ICCCM-compliant programs assume that.

(2) (key-mapping/warning) 
    The semantics of the modifier bits ModShift, ModLock, and ModControl
    are predefined.  It does not make sense to assign ModControl to any
    keysym other than Control_L or Control_R, or to assign any modifier
    bits to the "control" keysyms other than ModControl.  You can't
    turn a "control" key into a "meta" key (or vice versa) by simply
    assigning the key a different modifier bit.  You must also make that
    key generate an appropriate keysym (Control_L, Meta_L, etc).

(3) (key-mapping/warning) XEmacs:  Shift_L (0x32) generates ModLock, which is nonsensical.
```

Is there any way to tell XEmacs to stop teaching me that my keyboard settings are "bad"?

Comment: XEmacs has been stalled at version 21.4 for many years. Now the GNU Emacs has proper GUI support I suggest you give it a try. More users/developers to sort out issues.